# fire the .click() event of this undetectable element without JQuery

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'm searching a way to fire up click event of this tag :

```
    <input src="GN/button_go.gif" alt="Go" align="absmiddle" border="0" type="image">
```

using java-script and not using JQuery selectors. this has NO Id or Name or something else to identified by selectors.
what do you affer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this by using  [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
document.querySelector("[src='GN/button_go.gif']").click();
```